# Database Configuration Assistant Warning

Tags: linux, oracle, port, enterprise, dbca

Im using Oracle Linux Enterprise 6.10, and when a use de dbca show this warning [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAicR.png) i don´t why i have a ip static and my host are correct [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFQ9f.png)

Comment: Have you checked the log file located at `/u01/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/orcl0111/emConfig.log`? We can speculate, but the log file will give you detailed info as to why the error occured. That error frequently happens when there is either A.) An existing EM instance is running, which is preventing you from allocating the ports to create a new instance or B.) Another process is using one or more of those ports, preventing DBCA from allocating them for use. Check the log file to know for sure.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XnJ8oqo6yj5C9QkTiNUAI9F3QMtnqAfQ/view?usp=sharing heres the log file but i dont understand nothing @cdb_dba so if you cand give me a feedback

Comment: It looks like Enterprise Manager is already running. Please try accessing it.